# Performance of outer apply with function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have several stored procedures that use an outer apply.  The query inside the outer apply is always the same, so I could build a common table valued function which gives me the obvious benefit of code re-use, but I'm wondering if there are performance implications either way.  Is there a hit I take if I call a function?

For example:

```
SELECT
    m.[ID],
    m.[MyField],
    o.[OtherField]
FROM
    [MyTable] m
OUTER Apply
(
    fMyFunction(m.[ID])
)
```

VS

```
SELECT
    mt.[ID],
    mt.[MyField],
    o.[OtherField]
FROM
    [MyTable] mt
OUTER Apply
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        ot.[OtherField]
    FROM
        [OtherTable] ot 
    WHERE
        ot.[ID] = m.[ID]
) o
```

Comment: Without wishing to be flippant, why not just try it and see? You can compare execution times and plans in SSMS to see what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` is your friend

Comment: @HeavenCore: It depends. See my answer.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I accept your point regarding `STATISTICS IO` (And +1'ed your answer for its excellent explanation) however - i was advising the use of STATISTICS **TIME** as a measure of duration, multistep actions would print multiple times in ms that can easily be totalled & compared - just as a general guide really

Comment: Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10604840/1379794) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends of function type:

1. If the function is an inline table-valued function then this function will be considered to be a "parameterized" view and `SQL Server` can do some optimization work.
2. If the function is multi-step table-valued function then is hard for `SQL Server` to optimize the statement and the output from `SET STATISTICS IO` will be misleading.

For the next test I used the `AdventureWorks2008` (you can download this database from CodePlex). In this sample database you may find an `inline table-valued function` named `[Sales].[ufnGetCheapestProduct]`:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Sales].[ufnGetCheapestProduct](@ProductID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT   dt.ProductID
            ,dt.UnitPrice
    FROM
    (
        SELECT   d.SalesOrderDetailID
                ,d.UnitPrice
                ,d.ProductID  
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.ProductID ORDER BY d.UnitPrice ASC, d.SalesOrderDetailID) RowNumber
        FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail d
        WHERE   d.ProductID = @ProductID
    ) dt
    WHERE   dt.RowNumber = 1
```

I created a new function named `[Sales].[ufnGetCheapestProductMultiStep]`. This function is a `multi-step table-valued function`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Sales].[ufnGetCheapestProductMultiStep](@ProductID INT)
RETURNS @Results TABLE (ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY, UnitPrice MONEY NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT  @Results(ProductID, UnitPrice)
    SELECT   dt.ProductID
            ,dt.UnitPrice
    FROM
    (
        SELECT   d.SalesOrderDetailID
                ,d.UnitPrice
                ,d.ProductID  
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.ProductID ORDER BY d.UnitPrice ASC, d.SalesOrderDetailID) RowNumber
        FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail d
        WHERE   d.ProductID = @ProductID
    ) dt
    WHERE   dt.RowNumber = 1;

    RETURN;
END
```

Now, we can run the next tests:

```
--Test 1
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, oa1.*
FROM    Production.Product p
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT   dt.ProductID
            ,dt.UnitPrice
    FROM
    (
        SELECT   d.SalesOrderDetailID
                ,d.UnitPrice
                ,d.ProductID  
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.ProductID ORDER BY d.UnitPrice ASC, d.SalesOrderDetailID) RowNumber
        FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail d
        WHERE   d.ProductID = p.ProductID
    ) dt
    WHERE   dt.RowNumber = 1
) oa1

--Test 2
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, oa2.*
FROM    Production.Product p
OUTER APPLY [Sales].[ufnGetCheapestProduct](p.ProductID) oa2

--Test 3
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, oa3.*
FROM    Production.Product p
OUTER APPLY [Sales].[ufnGetCheapestProductMultiStep](p.ProductID) oa3
```

And this is the output from `SQL Profiler`:
[image]

**Conclusion**: you can see that using a query or an inline table-valued function with `OUTER APPLY` will give you the same performance (logical reads). Plus: [the multi-step table-valued functions are (usually) more expensive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/28/query-performance-and-multi-statement-table-valued-functions.aspx).

**Note**: I do not recommend using `SET STATISTICS IO` to measure the `IO` for scalar and multi-step table valued functions because the results can be wrong. For example, for these tests the output from `SET STATISTICS IO ON` will be:

```
--Test 1
Table 'SalesOrderDetail'. Scan count 504, logical reads 1513, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

--Test 2
Table 'SalesOrderDetail'. Scan count 504, logical reads 1513, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

--Test 3
Table '#064EAD61'. Scan count 504, logical reads 1008 /*WRONG*/, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

`Outer Apply` should not be considered here...

**Reason**

It will Iterate for each record of the `MyTable` and will search corresponding record in the `Outer Apply` table, despite of the fact that you will get all records from MyTable. So it should be instead replaced with Join(Left/Inner). This will speed up the query especially when you have large number of records to be fetched.

**[Check the difference between Apply and Join](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/18/sql-server-cross-apply.aspx)**